# "bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off” error when running shellcode"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, c

I'm writing shellcode to exploit a buffer overflow vulnerability on a server. To do so I have port binding shellcode that I send to the server and then I run (from a linux terminal) the command telnet serverAdress 4444 where 4444 is the port which I have opened up. The hope is that I will receive a shell back that I can use to execute commands. However, I always end up with the command

bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off

I can't change any of the server code, and I believe the shellcode is correct because I got it from this website (http://www.tsirogiannis.com/exploits-vulnerabilities-videos-papers-shellcode/linuxx86-port-binding-shellcode-xor-encoded-152-bytes/). From my research, it appears that this may have to do with the mode that my terminal is running in (something called interactive mode...or something like that).

All computers involved are linux machines and the machine that I am on is running the latest version of Ubuntu.

Any ideas what this job control error means and how I can fix it?

Comment: Possible reason is explained in the below thread,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529881/qemu-bin-sh-cant-access-tty-job-control-turned-off

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove `/dev/console`

```
cd /dev
rm -f console
ln -s ttyS0 console
```

edit/change the `/etc/inittab` content

```
::askfirst:/bin/sh
```

to:

```
ttyS0::askfirst:/bin/sh
```

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: Probably because the console is not allowed by the shell to be a `controlling` terminal. But I have no idea why that is.

Comment: How to make the edit "::askfirst:/bin/sh" to "ttyS0::askfirst:/bin/sh".
What commands should be given ?
Bcoz it says "/bin/sh:  ::askfirst:/bin/sh: not found"

Answer (score 4):

This mean that advanced commands such as Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+C are not available, because sh is not writing to a tty, but to a socket. For this reason, sh will not support background processes (`command &`) and the associated bg/fg/disown/jobs commands. But note that processes forking themselves and closing their inputs will still work.

You might have noticed that if a background jobs tries to read data from the terminal, the shell stops it (as in, SIGSTOP) and informs you that it has paused the process. If the shell does not do so, you have a race condition and what you write may end up in the background process or in the shell. This makes for an interesting and infuriating mess in your shell session.

Either use a more elaborate shellcode that creates a virtual terminal (but that's not a shellcode anymore once that happens), or just be aware that your ugly hack has limitations.

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the command of the shell, try:`sh +m` instead of `sh`. That worked perfectly for me.

Comment: this will disable job control completely, and only remove the initial warning `job control turned off`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Debian Mate. I just run an fsck from a live usb on dev/sda1 where / directory was installed.

Hope I helped someone

Answer (score 0):

see also [systemd-nspawn and sh: can't access tty; job control turned off #1431](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1431#issuecomment-393347607)

> same issue as [#8577](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8577) and [#8704](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8704)
>
> opening `/dev/tty` returns `ENXIO`,
> calling `setsid -c -w /bin/sh` workarounds these 3 issues
>
> nspawn calls `setsid()`
> but not `ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCSCTTY, 1)` as `setsid -c` does
>
> However, regarding posix, opening `/dev/tty` should not fail. The right solution is probably what @poettering suggest in [#8577](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8577): allocate `/dev/console` as a `pty` instead of mounting it from the outside.

when i do `less /dev/tty` in a broken terminal (job control is off),
i get `less: can't open '/dev/tty': No such device or address`

when i do `less /dev/tty` in a working terminal (job control is on),
less can open and read the file

`less /dev/console` throws `Permission denied` in both terminals,
broken and working

note that `setsid` is available only on unix, see also python's [os.setsid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.setsid)

see also [QEMU: /bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529881/qemu-bin-sh-cant-access-tty-job-control-turned-off)

> Apart from Accepted answer, as a get around `cttyhack` of busybox can be used.
>
> ```
> setsid cttyhack sh
> exec /bin/sh
> ```

Answer (score -5):

Guys I had the same problem but hopefully I fix it

There is how to fix this problem
Reinstall the Kali Linux system then when it came in disk partition you must delete all other disk just only left 1 disk and then hit continue then write all files in one disk hope I helped

Comment: I failt to see how this can have any relation with question.